# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (59): y , R

Tags: r

Tengo un data.frame con 59 filas, de la siguiente forma:

```
   ventas viajes entregas cajas.viaje cajas.entrega entregas.viaje  CP.viaje         Fechas
1  74336    146     1780    509.1507      41.76180       12.19178 1.0136986        2020-08-03
2  96712    179     3157    540.2905      30.63415       17.63687 0.9162011        2020-08-04
3  89996    150     2749    599.9733      32.73772       18.32667 1.0933333        2020-08-05
4  77958    160     2645    487.2375      29.47372       16.53125 1.0000000        2020-08-06
5  89830    174     3201    516.2644      28.06311       18.39655 0.9827586        2020-08-07
6  59336    137     1552    433.1095      38.23196       11.32847 1.0656934        2020-08-10
```

Quiero hacer regresiones lineales y representarlas con el diagrama de dispersión de puntos junto a la recta. Aquí un ejemplo.

```
r1=lm(ventas~ viajes)
summary(r1)
r1
b0 <- r1$coefficients[1]
b1 <- r1$coefficients[2]
b0
b1

ggplot(data=datos)+
geom_point(mapping=aes(x = viajes, y = ventas, color="blue" )) +
       geom_abline(mapping= aes(y=r1)) +
  geom_text( mapping= aes(label = paste("Ventas^", " = ", b0, " + ", b1, "*","viajes")))
```

Pero al representar, obtengo un error :
**Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (59): y**

Y no sé como solucionar, pues había probado con un código idéntico a un ejemplo de Rpubs.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La función `geom_abline()` lleva dos argumentos en el mapeo: `aes(intercept = ordenada_al_origen, slope = pendiente)`

Ya tienes esa información como `b0` y `b1`, así este código debería funcionar:

```
ggplot(data=datos)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x = viajes, y = ventas, color="blue" )) +
  geom_abline(mapping= aes(intercept = b0, slope = b1))
```

De todas maneras la forma "natural" de hacer esto con ggplot es usando `geom_smooth()`. Para un gráfico de puntos con `xy` definidos ajusta un modelo y grafica la pendiente. Por defecto ajusta un modelo general aditivo (permite curvas), pero le puede indicar el tipo de modelo que quieres usar. En tu caso:

```
ggplot(data=datos)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x = viajes, y = ventas, color="blue" )) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE)
```

El tipo de modelo se especifica en el argumento `method`, que debe recibir una cadena de caracteres. En este `lm` indica que es un linear model. Si no quieres que salga la banda de error estándar (standar error) puedes usar `se = FALSE`.